# setting up haproxy to listen to ssl

Tags: haproxy

I followed the instructions at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-implement-ssl-termination-with-haproxy-on-ubuntu-14-04 to setup haproxy to listen to ssl.

However when i try to hit any request through https it doesn't seem to be working, i basically get a ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

I started haproxy by outputting all the operations into nohup. I tried looking into nohup and i dont seem to be getting any info there when i hit the request.

Basically this is the config that i added:

```
frontend https
bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/{domainname.com}.pem
reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
default_backend default
```

While generating the certificate i have the same domainname.com as well.

Is there any other way to find out why it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: On the linux box where you have configured haproxy, if you do a `telnet server-ip 443` is it workin or says connection refused?! Also are you sure that the haproxy service is started?! You could issue a `/etc/init.d/haproxy` status to check if the service is actually running

Answer (score 1):

You can use "openssl" to verify the certificate response:

```
echo | openssl s_client -showcerts -connect yourdomain:443
```

or try "curl":

```
curl -v -o /dev/null https://yourdomain
```

check if your haproxy logging is enabled and correct, e.g.:

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1 local0

defaults
    log global
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was able to make this work, my haproxy configuration wasn't setup correctly. The certificate i created was a self-signed one by following the instructions at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-ubuntu-14-04. when i do a `curl -v -o /dev/null domain:443` it gives an error `curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: Invalid certificate chain`. I tried adding option `crt-ignore-err all` but that also didn't help. Is there a way to bypass this error or do i need to get a certificate from a trusted certificate authority?

Comment: Sorry should have been more explicit. using curl was just an example. Basically is there a way to bypass this error no matter what the client i'm using. So if i hit my url in browser it shows up a warning page with ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID.

Comment: Btw my haproxy version is 1.4.24.

Comment: nope - when you use a self sign certificate all clients will report this. you cannot say on server side "please ignore my self sign certificate" ;)
or you use a official certificate (e.g. lets encrypt certificates are free)